# Javascript: simplifying code, confused

Tags: javascript, simplify

I have enough knowledge when it comes to HTML/CSS/PHP/MySQL, but Javascript is still a huge hurdle for me. For whatever reason my teacher wants us to simplify this silly bit of code, but how would one go about doing that?

```
function f(a, b, c) {
    return function() {
        return a[b](c);
    }
}
window.onload = f(document, "write", "hi!");
```

I've thought of

```
function f(a, b, c) {
    return a[b](c);
}
window.onload = f(document, "write", "hi!");
```

but it can't simply be this simple, right? A push in the right direction would be much obliged!

edit: Thanks guys. Rather than giving me a push you've gone out of your ways (an insane amount of people even, whoa) to create this for me. Luckily all he wanted to know was how I would go about doing this, and that's all the Javascript for this year. Much obliged!

Comment: second one runs the function right away...

Comment: Your 2 examples aren't equivalent.  The 1st one returns a function (a closure).  The 2nd returns `undefined` as the function is ran immediately.

Comment: @Mave, Look at my answer, it's the simplest way to write equivalent code to your first sample. The solution proposed by @bigcakes is not equivalent since he disregards the `window.onload` handler.

Comment: I love people helping you do your homework. Hopefully your teacher roams here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think he wants you to realize that calling `f` returns another function.

```
function f(a, b, c) {
    return function() {
        return a[b](c);
    }
}
```

This is a function that, when run, returns another function. So

```
window.onload = f(document, "write", "hi!");
```

ends up being something like

```
window.onload = function() { return a[b](c); }
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are bound to the values you passed in. So write something like that, but replace `a`, `b`, and `c` with the right values. It ends up being `return document["write"]("hi")` which can also be written `return document.write("hi")`. Plug that in:

```
window.onload = function() {
    return document.write("hi");
}
```

This is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Or just 
`document["write"]("hi");`

Another way would be`document.write("hi");`

Edit: Oops, forgot you needed to do this onload,

```
window.onload = function() {
    return document.write("hi");
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not equivalent however since you are missing the onload handler.

Comment: Yeah, that one was even more obvious, but I disregarded that as being way too simple.. might as well give it a shot though. Thanks man! edit: whoops, onload handler missing

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that you needed to do this onload, sorry about that!  Good luck with javascript, it is a lot of fun.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe he's simply thinking of

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.write("hi");
};
```

(which is by the way a silly example, that waits for a page to load just to overwrite it with "hi".)

Answer (score 2):

This perhaps?

```
window.onload = document.write.bind(document, 'hi!');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed solution doesn't work: `document.write` will run immediately when `f` is called, rather than in response to the `load` event. The original function `f` actually *returns* a new function; your example immediately *calls* a function and returns the result.

If you look at the [MDN page on `window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload), you'll see that `onload` should be set to a function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  init();
  doSomethingElse();
};
```

It's obvious that the code should `document.write` a message, so put that code inside an `onload` function handler. You'll have shorter (but much less abstract) code that achieves the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your instructor wants to keep the function abstract, that is, without values embedded in it. That way you can pass ANY object, method, and value to it and it will work. Yours is very close. Others have drawn attention to some issues. This should work if you want the code to execute as the page loads:

```
function f(a, b, c) {
    a[b](c);
}
f(document, "write", "hi!");
```

You could keep the onload handler, but be aware that it will totally overwrite the existing document. Maybe the dude wants that. It sounds dumb, though. That would look like this:

```
function f(a, b, c) {
    a[b](c);
}
window.onload = function () {
    f(document, "write", "hi!");
};
```